# Include Gradle dependencies in the classpath of a debug launch of another project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I have a project with Gradle dependencies (say *projectA*) that, in order to debug it, is included in the class path of another project (say *rootProject*). The *rootProject* scans the classpath and loads *projectA* at runtime.

When I run *rootProject*, it says that dependencies of *projectA* are not found, by throwing a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig
    at be.vervaeck.sam.spongerest.RESTServer.<init>(RESTServer.java:18) ~[RESTServer.class:?]
    at be.vervaeck.sam.spongerest.RESTServer.<init>(RESTServer.java:27) ~[RESTServer.class:?]
    at be.vervaeck.sam.spongerest.SpongePlugin.onServerStart(SpongePlugin.java:25) ~[SpongePlugin.class:?]
    at org.spongepowered.common.event.listener.GameStartedServerEventListener_SpongePlugin_onServerStart2.handle(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.spongepowered.common.event.RegisteredListener.handle(RegisteredListener.java:86) ~[RegisteredListener.class:?]
    at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:238) [SpongeModEventManager.class:?]
    at org.spongepowered.mod.event.SpongeModEventManager.post(SpongeModEventManager.java:282) [SpongeModEventManager.class:?]
    at org.spongepowered.mod.SpongeMod.onStateEvent(SpongeMod.java:184) [SpongeMod.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:211) [LoadController.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:189) [LoadController.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275) [guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.onPost(LoadController.java:53) [LoadController.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118) [LoadController.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.serverStarted(Loader.java:800) [Loader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler.handleServerStarted(FMLCommonHandler.java:289) [FMLCommonHandler.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:510) [MinecraftServer.class:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_74]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    ... 34 more
```

In Eclipse, how can I make sure *projectA*'s dependencies are included in the class path of the debug session of *rootProject*?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a [project dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:project_dependencies) in build.gradle. Eg:

```
project(':rootProject') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':projectA')
    }
}
```

Comment: note that for this to work, the subprojects need to be included in the root project's settings.gradle